# How to dynamically create new Sound objects based on raw WAV / DATA or other Sound object?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, audio, dynamic, signal-processing

Is there any AS3 library or code-snippet that can create altered versions of a Sound object on-the-fly (at runtime)? Either based on:

- An existing Sound object;
- A ByteArray object;
- Some other audio file format source;

For example, say you have a ***"dry"*** sound of a gun-shot. You could:

- Make a ***Reverberated*** version to make it sound *distant*;
- Make a ***Low-pass filtered*** version to make it sound *next room / next door*;
- Make a ***Ping-Pong delay*** version of it to make it sound *cavernous*;

If this pre-processing happens before game-play begins, then all you have to do is play the altered Sound objects. That would eliminate the need to use the **SampleDataEvent API** which still consumes quite a bit of CPU power.

So, can `Sound` objects be *created* and *populated* with audio content at runtime?

**UPDATE:**

To further clarify my question, I am looking for a way to compile Sound objects at runtime, not "*synthesize*" or "*stream*" audio with the **SampleDataEvent API** (the CPU Usage can still be too intense).

My ultimate goal is to easily create duplicates of certain dry sounds pre-embedded in my library (or external SWF/SWC), but alter them with various filters at runtime before they're compiled to a Sound object (probably with some dynamic SWF generation hackery).

You can imagine it being like... using a *DAW* audio software to load an existing Sound source, process it offline with filters of your choice (LP, HP, Reverb, Delay, Distortion...), render it, adding it to a new Flash document's library, setting a Class name, and Voila! Your final result is what would play in the duplicated (but altered) Sound object.

If you know of any ActionScript 3.0 libraries (SWC or sources) that can do this kind of offline DSP treatment to sound, I'd love to hear about it.

Comment: Research Update: I've found this library that can load ByteArrays and convert them to Sound objects (MP3Parser). http://www.flexiblefactory.co.uk/flexible/?p=46#more-46Ideally however, the data could be generated from a series of values from 0.0 to 1.0 like in use of SampleDataEvent.

Comment: You can also look to FLOD project (http://www.photonstorm.com/flod). I mean there is no realtime sound mixer for flash (therefore i haven't found none when i was looking for), but you can use FLOD project as base for your own one. But even playing .mod .xm and .s3m with software player on as3 is very costly.

Comment: I remember [reading something](http://www.kevingoldsmith.com/labs/PBSynth-v1/) about somebody using pixel benders to process audio data. It might be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With Flash Player 11, you can use [Sound.loadPCMFromByteArray](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/beta/reference/actionscript/3/flash/media/Sound.html#loadPCMFromByteArray%28%29) to create a Sound from ByteArray at runtime, and you can process the PCM ByteArray to get your wanted effect, then create a Sound with it.
You can refer to [green sock volume example](http://www.greensock.com/tweenmax/) (or other libs) to find out how to process sound, I have not too much idea about this ;o)